# NullReferenceException was Unhandled "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, nullreferenceexception

I have a problem sending data to my access database.

I get this error

> NullReferenceExeption was Unhandled - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`on this part of my code`maxrows = ds.Tables("asdf").Rows.Count

What would that mean?

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    ID = TextID.Text
    FName = Textfname.Text
    LName = Textlname.Text
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    If TextID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO asdf(ID,fname,lname) " & _
        "VALUES(' " & TextID.Text & "', '" & Textfname.Text & "', '" & Textlname.Text & "')", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE asdf" & _
        "SET ID=" & TextID.Text & _
        ", fname='" & Textfname.Text & "'" & _
        ",lname ='" & Textlname.Text & "'" & _
        ", WHERE ID =" & TextID.Tag
    End If

    btnClear.PerformClick()

    MessageBox.Show("Data successfully saved!")
    maxrows = ds.Tables("asdf").Rows.Count ' <---- Exception occurs here
    inc = 1
    con.Close()
    RefreshData()

End Sub
```

Comment: You get this error when you try to invoke a method on an object that is null.  In this case it means either your data set ds or the table is null.

Comment: how will i fix this error? im sorry im just new to vb programming.

Comment: Well, I'd start with the **ds** object.  Where is it declared?  I don't see it anywhere in the code you listed.

Comment: Dim ds As DataSet,, i declared it in Class Form

Comment: Well, you have declared it, (otherwise your code will not compile) but, ds need to be initialized somewhere and filled with tables. Do you have `ds = New DataSet()` and `daAdapter.Fill(ds)` or do you have added manually tables to this dataset? You can't use ds without the first code and you can't use tables inside the dataset without the second code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Put a break-point (F9 or click in the margin) on this line of code: `maxrows = ds.Tables("asdf").Rows.Count` and run it.

Take these steps:

- Hover over `ds` or right-click and select Quick Watch and see if it
  says `null`.
- If it doesn't, highlight `ds.Tables("asdf")` and Quick Watch it and
  see if it's `null`.
- If not, then highlight `ds.Tables("asdf").Rows` and see if that's
  `null`.

One of these has to be null if it's crashing there. If that's the case, then you didn't fill it correctly or there wasn't nothing to fill it with.